# Atmosphere framework examples do not work. Any idea?

Tags: java, atmosphere

Perhaps I am going mad, but I've spent the whole day just trying to get the standard samples on the atomosphere (https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/) to work. Specifically the 'chat'. The instructions are simple - I follow them:

```
mvn package
cd samples/chat
mvn jetty:run
```

I visit localhost:8080 and I see the default page - it tells me it connects to the websockets. I see on the Jetty logs it registers the connection. I enter the 'user name' as requested, and then I get a javascript error '**WebSocket not connected**.' - after a couple of minutes it says "**Connection lost, trying to reconnect. Trying to reconnect 5000**" upon which it then connects and works without any issues. Its the same on Chrome, firefox and Safari. Its also the same on 2 different Macs (mavericks) and 1 Windows 7 PC. It consistently fails like this. I have no firewall, proxy , etc running.

I am going out of my mind, and I cannot proceed with my work/project. Its getting late here and I'm dreading another whole day at this getting no where. Any ideas or can some just test this to make sure I'm not going mad? I posted on the user group but just got '*its your environment*'. I've tried 3 environments and it makes no difference.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think this 'Fix' has broken the samples;

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-javascript/issues/74

debugging the atmosphere.js I see that webSocketOpened = true; is never set, and hence why the client can't send any messages as it thinks the connection is not open even though it is.

If I used client 2.1.4-SNAPSHOT the samples work fine.